# Fetch rows and check if has same value

Tags: php, mysql, compare, fetch

I'm very new to coding and trying to learn PHP and MYSQL. What I'm trying to do is, grouping the same CustomerID querys in the same table while making an echo. At the moment, my code echos all the querys seperated. I have a table like

```
ID      CustomerID     DATE        Company
1           1       2018-11-19        A
2           1       2018-11-19        A
3           2       2018-11-19        B
4           3       2018-11-19        C
5           4       2018-11-19        D
6           4       2018-11-19        D
```

My code

```
$query = "SELECT `customers`.ID, `customers`.customerid, `customers`.date
        FROM `customers` WHERE month(DATE)= month(CURRENT_DATE()) AND YEAR(DATE) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE());

$result = $mysqli->query($query);

while($resultquery = $result->fetch_array())

{
$queryresult[] = $resultquery;

}
if (!empty($queryresult)) {

foreach($queryresult as $queryresults)
{

$id = $queryresults['id'];
$customerid = $queryresults['customerid'];  
$date = $queryresults['date'];
?>
```

Then I echo it and the result is

```
Company Name: A
ID CustomerID DATE
1      1    2018-11-19

Company Name: A
ID CustomerID DATE
2      1    2018-11-19

Company Name: B
ID CustomerID DATE
3      2    2018-11-19

Company Name: C
ID CustomerID DATE
4      3    2018-11-19

<?php }} ?>
```

Etc..

But what I want is to compare customerID's and if there is more than one with same id, echo them as a group in the table.

```
Company Name: A
ID CustomerID DATE
1      1    2018-11-19
2      1    2018-11-19

Company Name: B
ID CustomerID DATE
3      2    2018-11-19

Company Name: C
ID CustomerID DATE
4      3    2018-11-19
```

I made an sql query with GROUP_CONCAT and used SEPARATOR '|') to group the result, it works but I dont think its the best to achieve this, so please help. Thank you

Comment: Your query contains a syntax error; a missing closing quote. Is that just a bad paste?

Comment: You could store the results in the array based off the `customerid`, ie `$queryresult[$resultquery['customerid'][] = $resultquery;`. Then you can loop over those to create your groups

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner yes it is. I have closing quote in my file.

Comment: @Sean can you re-write my code with an explanation please? I dont know how to loop exactly and get the data from it. Thank you

Comment: I don't see any of your code past `foreach($queryresult as $queryresults) {`, so I don't how I can re-write the code. I don't see where `Company Name: A` is coming from

Comment: @Sean table structure is ID CustomerID Date Company.

Company Name: <?php echo $Company ?> etc.I just need a simple example to understand and re-produce it. Also you can write it as an answer so I can approve it as an accepted answer. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map your data in a key-value array with **Company** as key (include company in the query:

$query = "SELECT `customers`.ID, `customers`.customerid, `customers`.date, company
        FROM `customers` WHERE month(DATE)= month(CURRENT_DATE()) AND YEAR(DATE) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())";

```
$query = "SELECT `customers`.ID, `customers`.customerid, `customers`.date
        FROM `customers` WHERE month(DATE)= month(CURRENT_DATE()) AND YEAR(DATE) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE());
```

Then simplify the data collection using a key to group items:

```
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$queryresult = [];
while($resultquery = $result->fetch_array())

{
 $company = $resultquery['company'];
 if (array_key_exists($company,$queryresult){
   @$queryresult[$company] = [];
 }
 @$queryresult[$company][] = $resultquery;

}
```

An then you can present the information using foreach:

```
foreach($queryresult as $company => $items){
   // header by company
   echo "Company Name: $company \n";
   echo "ID CustomerID DATE\n";
   foreach($items as $item){
     // items in company
     echo "{$item['id']} {$item['customerid']} {$item['date']}\n"; 
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping but I get that error;

Warning: Illegal offset type in report.php on line 54


 $queryresult[$resultquery['group'][] = $resultquery;

Comment: You can add @ at `@$queryresult[$company][] = $resultquery;` to avoid this warning. It's because you are creating a new inexistent key for each group. Otherwise you can do a key check. I updated the example code.

Comment: The code works now I made a mistake while implementing it though it does not groups the company. It doesnt show the second query for the same company. There should be 5 record outputs which, 2 A company, 1 B, 2 C, 1 D but its like A1 B1 C1 D1

Comment: I changed

if (array_key_exists($company,$queryresult)) {
 
 @$queryresult[$company] = [];

to

if (array_key_exists($customerid,$queryresult)) {
 
 @$queryresult[$customerid] = [];

and it works now. Thank you very much!